# dataTable not displaying the data

Tags: ajax, datatables

i am trying to load data in datatable using ajax, this is my table definition:

```
 <table id="appointments" class="display" width="100%">
                             <thead>
                               <tr>
                                <th>Activité</th>
                                <th>Pour le</th>
                                <th>Heure Début</th>
                                <th>Heure Fin</th>
                                <th>Référent</th>
                                <th>Etat</th>
                                <th>test</th>
                                <th>test2</th>
                                <th>test3</th>
                              </tr> 
                             </thead>
                               <tbody>
                                
                               </tbody>                        
                       </table>
```

and this is the  ajax call:

```
     $("#appointments").dataTable({
                                        "searching":false,
                                        "ajax":function(data,callback,settings){
                                                $.ajax({
                                                    url:"http://test.azprojet.fr/wsazprojet/api/entreprise/ManageAppointements",
                                                    datatype:"json",
                                                    type:"get",
                                                    data:{
                                                        domainName:$("[name='url']").val(),
                                                        IdUsager:$('input[name="IdUsager"]').val()
                                                    },
                                                    success:function(data,html,status){
                                                    
                                                        
                                                                            
                                                        },
                                                        error:function(html,status,error){
                                                            console.log("new error have occured")
                                                            console.log(error)
                                                        }
                                                });}
                                            });
```

when i apply this code , i get an empty dataTable containing the word "loading" ?
[image]
what 's wrong ?

## update

it looks like that i missed calling **callback(data)** inside the success function , however after adding that i get this error :

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

searching for solution i found that i need to set ajax.dataSrc inside the ajax object , but i didn't know how since i m calling a function here !

Comment: did u check the api url u calling ?

Comment: yes it works i can see the data in console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that , datatable accept this format of json data:

```
{ 
   "data": [
  {
     "name": "Tiger Nixon",
     "position": "System Architect",
     "salary": "$320,800",
     "start_date": "2011/04/25",
     "office": "Edinburgh",
     "extn": "5421"
    }
 ]
}
```

so the solution was to add wrap my data like this :

```
data={"data":data}
```